# How to get a particular gcc version on debian armhf?

Tags: debian, apt, gcc

I need gcc 4.9.3 installed on my armhf debian box. But the version in the jessie repositories are 4.9.2 and the version in stretch is 5.

How can i get a particular version through the repositories?

Comment: Why do you specifically need version 4.9.3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stretch currently has [version 4.9.3](https://packages.debian.org/source/testing/gcc-4.9), but that's about to be replaced by 4.9.4. You can get the last set of packages for 4.9.3 reliably from [Debian snapshots](http://snapshot.debian.org/package/gcc-4.9/4.9.3-14/), including for `armhf`. The corresponding repository is

```
deb http://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian/20160415T115342Z/ sid main
```

(see the instructions given on the main [snapshots](http://snapshot.debian.org/) page for details of how to use this).

Comment: thanks! does that mean 4.9.3 will be moving to jessie?

Comment: when i select `apt-get install gcc/stretch` i get `Selected version '4:5.3.1-3' (Debian:testing [armhf]) for 'gcc'` Isn't that 5.3.1?

Comment: Jessie only gets updates for serious bugs or security issues; there won't be an upgrade to GCC 4.9.3 there. To install GCC 4.9 in Strech you need to ask for it explicitly (see my first link): `apt-get install gcc-4.9/stretch`.

Comment: thanks.. figured it out eventually. was hoping for a solution for this bug https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=71776 but it's still there. fingers crossed for 4.9.4